# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException while storing resource output in JsonObject

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I'm trying to automate REST API using Jersey Client library hence I've following dependencies in my pom.xml -

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and code is like following -

```
@Test
public void test(){
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://md5.jsontest.com/");
    WebTarget zipTarget = webTarget.queryParam("text", 123);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = zipTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    JSONObject jsonObject = invocationBuilder.get(JSONObject.class);
}
```

But it results into following error for `JSONObject jsonObject = invocationBuilder.get(JSONObject.class);` -

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "original" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@19b89d4; line: 2, column: 17] (through reference chain: org.json.JSONObject["original"])
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:809)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at jerseyclienttest.JerseyTest.test(JerseyTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "original" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@19b89d4; line: 2, column: 17] (through reference chain: org.json.JSONObject["original"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:834)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1094)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1470)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1448)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:282)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1580)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:961)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:806)
    ... 37 more
```

Can you please help to understand what else dependencies needed here or is it something wrong with API itself?

Answer (score 1):

This is setting up the data retrieval from the url which will return `JSON`:

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://md5.jsontest.com/");
```

and this is turning that `JSON` into a Java object:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = invocationBuilder.get(JSONObject.class);
```

`UnrecognizedPropertyException` means the returned `JSON` does not match any members in the Java object `JSONObject`. If the returned JSON was:

```
{
  "new": "ok",
  "original": "notok"
}
```

The Java class that would produce that error would be:

```
class Result {
  private String new;

  // getters/setters
}
```

the class that would fix the error would be:

```
class Result {
  private String new;
  private String original;

  // getters/setters
}
```

or

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
class Result {
  private String new;

  // getters/setters
}
```

but the issue is, you're passing `JSONObject`, a built-in class. You need to create your own class to handle the returned `JSON` that matches the `JSON` schema you're using.

Comment: thanks for providing all these details to make it clear to understand!